# C# XmlSerializer from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xml-serialization

I have 2 classes:

```
 [XmlInclude(typeof(Item))]
 public class A
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [XmlArray("Items")]
     [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
     public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
 }

 public class Item
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [XmlIgnore]
     public virtual A a { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm using this method inside my `DbContext`:

```
public virtual DbSet<A> A { get; set; }

public IQueryable<A> GetA()
{
      return A;
}
```

Now I want to export data to XML:

```
Type[] types = { typeof(Item) };

var aElements = GetA().ToList();

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
     new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(aElements.GetType(), types);

writer.Serialize(file, aElements);
```

And it throws an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.A_08D7BCCB892E27DE8C32342A0E8F0F2B2D3B9E2DAC9F6A16 was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

What's wrong? I tried to search similar topics, but those solutions doesn't work for me.

Edit: expected result:

```
<A>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Items>
     <Item><Id>20</Id></Item>
  </Items>
</A>
<A>
  ..
</A>
```

Comment: Looks good. There is no mistake. Are there another details which you didn't provided ?

Comment: that's almost everything, just those classes has more attributes but just primitive types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting this error because Entity Framework substitutes your collection of Items with Proxies to Items to support lazy loading.
The XmlSerializer doesn't expect the dynamically generated proxy type, hence the error.

You can probably solve this by turning of Lazy Loading for that Items collection property.  Keep in mind that, by turning off lazy-loading, the Items collection will always be populated, so it might give you some unexpected performance hits in some cases.

Comment: yeah, I just figured it out. I just need to turn it off and include items manually. Otherwise there would be loop of lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps should be;

```
public virtual DbSet<A> A{ get; set; }
public IQueryable<A> GetA()
{
      return A.AsNoTracking();
}
```

Comment: already tried but same error. I also updated my question, I'm serializing list of A class.

Comment: It would work. So, would you try turning off proxy creation. DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Comment: Also, already tried. That stops throwing an error but <Items></Items> are empty.

Comment: Maybe you can try deep copy and then serializing it.

Comment: This line is causing that error: public virtual A a { get; set; } not sure how to fix it, though.